# Laravel : delete the welcome page and need to restore it

Tags: laravel

I need help. I am a new user Laravel. I delete by mistake Welcome.blade.php.
How can restore this please.
Thank for your answer

Comment: Get it from Laravel's repository or install Laravel to a different location and copy it from there

Comment: I have it, it's good I thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from [Laravel git repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

Comment: I have it, it's good I thank you